# MySQL syntax error: I'm stuck

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

```
$queryStatus = mysql_query("INSERT into `database`.`users` (`first`, `last`, `pass`, `user`, `id`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$password', '$user', NULL, '$email', '0'") or die("BAD QUERY: " . mysql_error());
```

The ID field is `NULL` because it is an auto-increment. But it is throwing a syntax error and I really can't find out why. Please help.

Comment: Next time you post a question because you receive a syntax error, include the actual error, makes it much easier to spot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore the ID field, it will insert the value automatically:

```
$queryStatus = mysql_query("INSERT into `database`.`users` (`first`, `last`, `pass`, `user`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$password', '$user', '$email', '0'") or die("BAD QUERY: " . mysql_error());
```

Also your query seems badly formed (incorrectly places quotation mark at end), I'm not sure about PHP specifically but this should work:

```
$queryStatus = mysql_query("INSERT into `database`.`users` (`first`, `last`, `pass`, `user`, `email`, `active`) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$password', '$user', '$email', '0')");
```

Comment: That is to say, exempt it from your column list `(first, last, pass, etc.)` then just populate the value columns you have.

Comment: There's still a syntax error due to the missing bracket on the VALUES clause.

Comment: @a'r yes I spotted a syntax error afterwards, I think it's the closing quotation.

Comment: The `,id,` and `,NULL,` in the `INSERT INTO` are not an error.

Comment: @yper, I know but I thought I would make the suggestion, I believe I have located the syntax error in the update.

Comment: OK, but when someone reads your answer for the first time, it looks as if you suggest that the inclusion of `id` causes the error.

Answer (score 3):

You do not close off the `VALUES ()` part of the query. There needs to be a close bracket at the end - don't confuse it with the close bracket for the `mysql_query` function call.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra double quotation mark (") right before the closing bracket that's stated before "or die".